# If I 'overwrite' a List with a 'new' List, is the old one deleted?

Tags: c#, list

I want to re-initialise a List in C# - essentially wipe it and fill it up again.

If I initialise the list again by assigning to it using the new keyword, is the old one still hanging around somewhere or have I successfully overwritten it?

Comment: It will overwrite it. And the old list will be around until the garbage collector collects it.

Comment: Nope. You will overwrite only variable that indicates on the list (variable will reference the new list). The old list will stay in a memory till Garbage Collector will take care (only if there won't any more references).

Comment: Depending on the contents you may first need to Dispose of some things to avoid GDI leaks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I initialise the list again by assigning to it using the new keyword, is the old one still hanging around somewhere or have I successfully overwritten it?

The old one will hang around for a while until the Garbage collector comes along.
Provided of course that you did not store a reference to the List anywhere else.

You can only overwrite the reference variable pointing to the List, not the List itself.

More important: in general, this is the right thing to do. Just create a new object/list when you need it, don't worry (hassle) with old state etc.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other references to that list, the list will be removed by the garbage collector.
Keep in mind that, if you have 2 variables referencing the same list, you assign a new list to 1 variable, but the other is still pointing towards the original list.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe that you want to do, and how you descibe that you want to do it doesn't match.

If you want to keep the `List<T>` object and wipe it, you would use the `Clear` method:

```
myList.Clear();
```

This will remove all items in the list, but you keep the same instance. It will also still have the same capacity, i.e. the underlying array that was used to hold the items is kept.

If you use the `new` keyword you will create a new instance. Example:

```
myList = new List<int>();
```

The reference to the new instance will replace the reference to the previous instance. Unless there is another reference to that instance, it will be up for garbage collection. The next time the garbage collector runs, it's likely that the previous instance will be removed.

There is no guarantee, though. If the list have lived for a long time it might have been moved to the second or third generation heap, in that case it will remain in memory until the garbage collector decides to do a collection of more than the first generation heap.